# Probability to z-score and vice versa

Tags: python, statistics

How do I calculate the `z score` of a `p-value` and vice versa?

For example if I have a p-value of `0.95` I should get `1.96` in return.

I saw some functions in scipy but they only run a z-test on an array.

I have access to numpy, statsmodel, pandas, and scipy (I think).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
>>> import scipy.stats as st
>>> st.norm.ppf(.95)
1.6448536269514722
>>> st.norm.cdf(1.64)
0.94949741652589625
```

[image: Default Python Probabilities]

As other users noted, Python calculates left/lower-tail probabilities by default. If you want to determine the density points where 95% of the distribution is included, you have to take another approach:

```
>>>st.norm.ppf(.975)
1.959963984540054
>>>st.norm.ppf(.025)
-1.960063984540054
```

[image: Density between two points]

Comment: For anyone else, like me, who was briefly confused by the request for a function which returned 1.96 but having the accepted answer give 1.64 -- the difference is that 1.96 is the zscore inside of which is 95% of the data (ignoring both tails), but st.norm.ppf() gives the zscore which has 95% of the data *below* it (ignoring only the upper tail).

Comment: (cont) If you want 1.96 from 0.95, you have to make use of the fact that the normal distribution is symmetric and divide the amount you're ignoring in half to get just the upper tail ignored: `st.norm.ppf(1-(1-0.95)/2) == 1.959963984540054` - Basic statistics, yes, but I just wanted to make it explicit.

Comment: Can anyone tell what python code was used to plot the above graphs?

Comment: @bobthebuilder Womp womp! The chart was actually generated using the [tigerstats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tigerstats/index.html) package from R (specifically [pnormGC](https://homerhanumat.github.io/tigerstats/qnorm.html)).

Answer (score 26):

Starting in `Python 3.8`, the standard library provides the [`NormalDist`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist) object as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module.

It can be used to get the `zscore` for which x% of the area under a normal curve lies (ignoring both tails).

We can obtain one from the other and vice versa using the [`inv_cdf`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.inv_cdf) (inverse cumulative distribution function) and the [`cdf`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.cdf) (cumulative distribution function) on the standard normal distribution:

```
from statistics import NormalDist

NormalDist().inv_cdf((1 + 0.95) / 2.)
# 1.9599639845400536
NormalDist().cdf(1.9599639845400536) * 2 - 1
# 0.95
```

<sub>An explanation for the '(1 + 0.95) / 2.' formula can be found in this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps) section.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in T-test, you can do similar:

- **z-statistics (z-score)** is used when the data follows a normal distribution, population standard deviation sigma is known and the sample size is above 30.  Z-Score tells you how many standard deviations from the mean your result is.  The z-score is calculated using the formula:

  z_score = (xbar - mu) / sigma
- **t-statistics (t-score)**, also known as **Student's T-Distribution**, is used when the data follows a normal distribution, population standard deviation (**sigma**) is **NOT** known, but the sample standard deviation (**s**) is known or can be calculated, and the sample size is below 30.  T-Score tells you how many standard deviations from the mean your result is.  The t-score is calculated using the formula:

  t_score = (xbar - mu) /  (s/sqrt(n))

**Summary:** If the sample sizes are larger than 30, the z-distribution and the t-distributions are pretty much the same and either one can be used.  If the population standard deviation is available and the sample size is greater than 30, t-distribution can be used with the population standard deviation instead of the sample standard deviation.

| test statistics | lookup table | lookup values | critical value | normal distribution | population standard deviation (sigma) | sample size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| z-statistics | z-table | z-score | z-critical is z-score at a specific confidence level | yes | known | > 30 |
| t-statistics | t-table | t-score | t-critical is t-score at a specific confidence level | yes | not known | < 30 |

Python **Percent Point Function** is used to calculate the critical values at a specific confidence level:

- **z-critical** `= stats.norm.ppf(1 - alpha) (use alpha = alpha/2 for two-sided)`
- **t-critical** `= stats.t.ppf(alpha/numOfTails, ddof)`

## Codes

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats


# alpha to critical
alpha = 0.05
n_sided = 2 # 2-sided test
z_crit = stats.norm.ppf(1-alpha/n_sided)
print(z_crit) # 1.959963984540054

# critical to alpha
alpha = stats.norm.sf(z_crit) * n_sided
print(alpha) # 0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Z-score to probability :**

[image]

The code snippet below maps the *negative of the absolute value* of the z-score to cdf of a Std Normal Distribution and multiplies by 2 . This will give the prob of finding the probability of Area1 + Area2 shaded in  the picture here :
[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm 


norm(0, 1).cdf(-np.absolute(zscore)) * 2
```

Ref: https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra2/Statistics/STzScores.html