# Julia: quantiles and confidence intervals

Tags: julia

Does Julia have a function to calculate the density points where `p%` of the distribution is included?

Something like the `scipy.stats` `norm.ppf` function mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864847/probability-to-z-score-and-vice-versa-in-python)

Example: 2-sided 95% confidence interval:

```
> norm.ppf(1-(1-0.95)/2)
1.96

> norm.ppf(1-(1+0.95)/2)
-1.96
```

Comment: P.S. I found a ``zscore`` function in the ``StatsBase`` package.

Comment: yes, was going to suggest that :-). You should post that as an answer to your own question, unless you are not satisfied with that?

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard, well I don't understand how to use it. Mostly I get ``MethodError``. If it's easy for you, please do post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I see what you mean now, I got confused by the heading. The `zscore` transforms all values of a vector by subtracting the mean of the vector and dividing by the stdev. It is very useful in statistics. I see you were after the probability cutoff - that is indeed `quantile` as answered by Dan Getz below.

Comment: Sorry for the poor wording, Michael. Feel free to edit the question to clarify it! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `quantile` function from Distributions package is probably (95% CI) what you are looking for. For the Normal distributions you have:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> quantile(Normal(0.0, 1.0),1-(1+0.95)/2)
-1.9599639845400576

julia> quantile(Normal(0.0, 1.0),1-(1-0.95)/2)
1.9599639845400576
```

The same function `quantile` can be used for other distributions.

Comment: Very probable indeed - I'd misunderstood the question :-)

Comment: I ended up using something like this: ``norm_ppf2(; p = .95) = quantile(Normal(0.0, 1.0), 1-(1+p)/2), quantile(Normal(0.0, 1.0), 1-(1-p)/2)``

Comment: Note that `quantile` can work for many distributions. So a more general approach would define `medianinterval(d,p=0.95) = quantile(d,1-(1+p)/2),quantile(d,(1+p)/2)`. This way you have `medianinterval(Exponential())` ≈ (0.0253,3.6889) as well.

Comment: ...and `Normal() == Normal(0.0,1.0)`, so with the definition above, `medianinterval(Normal())` would give the standard (-1.96,1.96)

Comment: @DanGetz nice example of an asymmetric distribution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another related enhancement to the answer, especially for users of Bayesian posteriors, we can define `medianinterval` as follows:

```
medianinterval(d,p = 0.95) = quantile(d,1-(1+p)/2),quantile(d,(1+p)/2)
```

and have:

```
julia> medianinterval(Normal())
(-1.9599639845400576, 1.9599639845400576)
```

But sometimes a more efficient (i.e. shorter) interval will be around the **mode** of the distribution. To address this we can define:

```
function modeinterval(d,p=0.95)
    mcdf = cdf(d,mode(d))
    endpoints = mcdf < p/2 ? (0,p) : mcdf > 1-p/2 ? (1-p,1) : (mcdf-p/2,mcdf+p/2)
    return map(x->quantile(d,x), endpoints)
end
```

For the Normal distribution it doesn't matter since the mode is also the median, but for other distributions such as the Beta, we can have:

```
julia> modeinterval(Beta(2,8),0.2)
(0.09639068616673087, 0.15355172436770012)

julia> medianinterval(Beta(2,8),0.2)
(0.1498495815725847, 0.21227857915644155)

julia> 0.15355172436770012 - 0.09639068616673087
0.05716103820096925

julia> 0.21227857915644155 - 0.1498495815725847
0.06242899758385684
```

The mode interval covers the same fraction of the distribution with a shorter length. See [Credible interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) for related discussion.

Comment: very neat! Note for self: the last two lines of code are the 'width' of the interval.