# Probability scores for distribution of two means

Tags: python, for-loop, normal-distribution

I have a 40-long list of means and variances relating to model error rates. I am looking to determine which models are statistically better (smaller error rates) than others.

Assuming error rates are normally distributed, I am presently looking up *z-scores* manually, which is working but taking a long time. Is there a more pythonic way to create a matrix of probability scores comparing, for instance, *model a* vs *model b*, *model b* vs *model c*, *model a* vs *model c*?

I haven't included any code thus far as I am currently working in excel, but have included the dummy sample below if anyone can assist.

```
data = [[10, 0.8],[5, 1.2],[12, 2.4],[6, 2.8]]
```

Comment: If your looking up z-scores manually you have some 'X' that you are using to compare models and see how many standard deviations away the value is right ?

Comment: also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864847/probability-to-z-score-and-vice-versa-in-python) question that deals with zscores to probabilities using the scipy package

Comment: Thanks @casualcoder - My question isn't fantastically worded but you've pointed me in the right direction.