# How to find percentage of values above the second standard deviation in python?

Tags: python, scipy.stats

Problem statement - Suppose a variable X has a bell-shaped distribution with a mean of 150 and a standard deviation of 20.
a. What percentage of X values lies above 190?

My code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.stats

X=scipy.stats.norm(150,20)
```

I know that 68% of X lie within 1 standard deviation ie (between 130 to 170) and 95% within 2 standard deviation (110 to 190).

But how to find percentage of values above 190?
(I wrote 2.50 as the answer but it was incorrect)

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to count the output from X or the theoretical percentage for the normal distribution.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Standard_deviation_diagram.svg) it is 2.2%

Comment: The first answer here has everything you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864847/probability-to-z-score-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sf()` (see section "methods" at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html):

```py
import scipy.stats

scipy.stats.norm(150, 20).sf(190) # result: 0.022750131948179195
```